# Code for button to delete specific entries from a MySQL table (using php)?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, my code prints out the contents of a mysql table and it contains a delete button. How can I get this button to delete the corresponding entry from the mysql table? Also, how can I make it so that the table only displays entries of a certain data (e.g. do not display entries from before the today's date)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

include('php/connect.php');

mysql_connect ($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db('booking');

$sql="SELECT *FROM bookings";
$records = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Records</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width = "600" border = "1" cellpadding = "1" cellspacing = "1">
<tr>

<th>ID</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Start</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>E-mail</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Delete</th>

</tr>

<form action="" method="post">

<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete']) and is_numeric($_POST['delete']))
{
        $sql = "";
}

while ($student = mysql_fetch_assoc ($records)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$student['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['start']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['phone']."</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type=submit name=delete id=".$student['id']." value=delete </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}

?>

</form>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is rather broad - how to do this is the subject of many tutorials on the web. It would be easier for you, in the long term at least, to do some study, so that when you want to build something, you know how to do it.

Comment: the second part can be done by the query e.g where date=NOW() and for the first part i guess you should have a look at ajax tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
<a href='delete.php?id=".$student['id']."'>Delete</a>
```

Simple put this in `td tag` and write query for delete in `delete.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']) and is_numeric($_REQUEST['delete']))
{
        $sql = "DELETE FROM bookings WHERE id=3";
}
while ($student = mysql_fetch_assoc ($records)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$student['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['start']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$student['phone']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?delete=".$student['id']."'>Delete</a> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</form>
```

*